# Looking for a way to implement an expression which takes an operation as an argument

Tags: c++

I have a class which can be in either one of two states.

Suppose that the member variable `m_bCond` determines the state of an object.

Now, in many of the class member functions, I have the following code-pattern:

```
if (m_bCond)
{
    do some operation on 'm_vector[m_index]'
}
else
{
    for (const auto& item : m_vector)
    {
        do some operation on 'item'
    }
}
```

Is there any good syntax which I can use in order to do it more "neatly"?

I want to be able to use some sort of expression, and pass the operation as an argument.

Something like:

```
Expression(operation)
{
    if (m_bCond)
    {
        do 'operation' on 'm_vector[m_index]'
    }
    else
    {
        for (auto item : m_vector)
        {
            do 'operation' on 'item'
        }
    }
```

It would be easy for me to do it in Python, for example, but I'm not really sure about C++.

I know it can be done with a macro, but that would leave me with a rather hard-to-debug piece of code. So I guess I'm looking for a Lambda of some sort, or a member function if possible.

Thank you.

Comment: [`std::function`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) maybe?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ `std::function` sounds like pointless overhead. Probably just a local lambda?

Comment: @lisyarus If you want to pass e.g. lambdas as parameter, you would need a `std::function`. As OP asked for operation as parameter ...

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ It isn't clear whether the OP talks about an actual function parameter or just calls the operation a "parameter". I'd advise templates in the former case, though.

Comment: @lisyarus The question is unclear yes, that's why I VTC.

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to make a generic function that accepts a lambda/functor/function and apply it to the vector or elements of the vector like so

```
template<typename Operation>
void apply(Operation operation)
{
    if (m_bCond)
    {
        operation(m_vector[m_index]);
    }
    else
    {
        for (auto item : m_vector)
        {
            operation(item);
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can use it like this(using a lambda to make the code shorter):

```
MyType foo;
//populate and set foo's members
// set condition to true
foo.apply([](auto& v){ v.push_back(10); });
// set condition to false
foo.apply([](auto& i){ i *= 42; });
```

Comment: Awesome. Looks just like what I (sort of) had in mind. One small question though: In some cases the operation changes the item / items, and in some cases it doesn't. This means that at present, my `for` loop sometimes uses `auto& item` and sometimes uses `const auto& item`. So would I need to implement two different functions, or can that single function in your answer be "templated" for both cases? Thanks again!!!

Comment: @goodvibration you can pass a lvalue reference to a function that expects an lvalue reference to `const`, so it will work fine as-is.